# How to print multiple values on the same line using Out-File

Tags: powershell

I want to calculate hash values for filenames and store the hash with its path. I do not want any header because I will use this list to compare to another pre-calculated list of hash values for the same paths. So the objective is to have a file containing hash value, space, path/filename on each line. Out-File seemed like a logical choice.

My code works:

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem $startfolder -exclude CHKSUMS.MD5) | foreach { $_.Hash,$_.Path} | out-file -FilePath $tempDir\PhysicalUSBHash.txt
```

but the result of out-file is:

```
HASH1
PATH1
HASH2
PATH2
```

and what I want is HASH delimited by a single space from PATH:

```
HASH1 PATH1
HASH2 PATH2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing it 2 separate values.

You can fix this by ensuring they're grouped together using the sub-expression array operator `@(...)`, and then use the `-Join` operator to join them using a space:

```
@($_.Hash,$_.Path) -Join ' '
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Powershell. Do I replace the foreach with the above or does this go after foreach? When I run it with foreach, I get: ForEach-Object: Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-Join" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". But if I don;'t use foreach, I get: "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what you currently have inside your `Foreach`, which is `$_.Hash,$_.Path`, should be replaced with the above.

Comment: Never mind, I was trying to replace the braces rather than put this inside them. Your answer was clear once I reread it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could do is combine results together in a variable. I find this useful sometimes, especially for formatting.

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem -path $startfolder -exclude CHKSUMS.MD5) | foreach {$Aggregate = $Aggregate+$_.Hash+" "+$_.Path+"`r"}
$aggregate | Out-String | out-file -FilePath $tempDir\PhysicalUSBHash.txt
```

(The escaped R above [`r] is a carriage return/new line.)

As an example, if spaces in the path might be an issue you can add in quotes relatively easily this way:

```
foreach {$Aggregate = $Aggregate+$_.Hash+" `""+$_.Path+"`"`r"}
```

Swapping this section in would add quotes to the path.

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but it never hurts to have more than one option available.

Comment: Great to know other ways of doing it! Thanks!